# Improper integral problem

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I am currently on this problem 
$$\int_{2}^{N}\frac{dt}{t\,(\log t)^{\frac{t+1}{t}}}$$

I tried to make substitution but it wouldn't work. That is, $x=\log t$ and my result was

$$\int_{2}^{N}\frac{dt}{t\,(\log t)^{\frac{t+1}{t}}}=\int_{\log 2}^{\log N}x^{-1-e^{-x}}dx.$$

I think I got it wrong somewhere. Please, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Another small nitpick: what makes such integral *improper*?

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio. It cannot be calculated using a normal Riemann integral.

Comment: @Omojola. It can be calculated as a normal Riemann integral. You just need to find it's antiderivate.

Comment: @  Botond. I tried it but got stuck. I have been successful in solving similar types but I got stuck in this one!

Comment: Is the problem to evaluate the integral or to determine whether the integral converges as $N\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to notice that
$$ \int_{2}^{N}\frac{dt}{t\log t}=\left[\log\log t\right]_{2}^{N} = \log\log N-\log\log 2\tag{1}$$
$$\forall \alpha>0,\qquad \int_{2}^{N}\frac{dt}{t\left(\log t\right)^{1+\alpha}}=\left[-\frac{1}{\alpha\left(\log t\right)^{\alpha}}\right]_{2}^{N}=-\frac{1}{\alpha\left(\log N\right)^{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{\alpha\left(\log 2\right)^{\alpha}}\tag{2} $$
hence by evaluating the RHS of $(2)$ at $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha=\frac{1}{N}$ we have that the given integral is convergent.
On the other hand, $\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^{1+\frac{1}{t}}}$ does not have an elementary primitive.

What is the actual statement of the original problem?

Comment: Thank you very much! The question aims at showing if  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\dfrac{1}{n(\text{log}\, n)^\frac{n+1}{n}}$ converges or not.

Comment: @Omojola: then integral comparison (or the explicit computation of a non-elementary antiderivative) is not the slickest approach. By Cauchy's condensation test, such series is convergent/divergent iff $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\cdot n^{1/e^n}}$$ is convergent/divergent. The last series is blatantly divergent by comparison with the harmonic series, so it is the former.

Comment: @  Jack D'Aurizio. I don't get you! I was trying to use the integral test. I know that if $$\text{lim}_N\rightarrow\infty \int_{n=2}^{N}f(t)dt$$ converges then $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}$$ also converges.

Comment: @Omojola: in this case the integral test and the condensation test are pretty much the same thing, but if you want to prove the divergence/convergence of your series you *do not need* a closed form for $\int_{2}^{N}f(t)\,dt$, but you *do need* to know if the limit of the previous integral as $N\to +\infty$ is finite or not. And that is not the point of the question above.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio. Sorry I didn't state it the right way. As it stands, can I make use of your solution? I have not seen a correlation yet!

Comment: @Omojola: you may use a slightly different form of $(2)$ to get that $$\int_{N/2}^{N}\frac{dt}{t\left(\log t\right)^{1+1/t}}$$ is unbounded, hence the original series is divergent. Or just follow my previous comment: for any $n$ large enough, $n^{1/e^n}$ is $\leq 2$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: Thank you! I'll try it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74840/discussion-between-omojola-and-jack-daurizio).